# How to export MS SQL database with extended properties?

Tags: sql-server, export

I'm trying to move a MS SQL database from one provider to another, but attributes such as auto_increment for primary keys aren't copying over.  I have MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008 installed, but I don't see any options to copy this properties over in the Import and Export wizard.  Can anyone explain how this is done? I'm not a Windows person at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are moving the database from one Microsoft SQL Server to another, you are better served by either using the "Copy Database..." wizard, or by taking a backup of the database and restoring it to the other server. The Export/Import wizards are for moving data to/from other database systems.